# PowerPoint 2010 won't open any files

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office-2010-beta

Recently I installed Office 2010 BETA on my friend's laptop after recommending it to her. The problem is, whenever she tries to open files in powerpoint it claims that there is a problem with them and it can attempt to repair them, when you click repair it just says there was a problem with the file and it can't open it.

The exact same .ppt files work fine on my copy of PowerPoint 2010 (we sent the file from her laptop to mine via MSN) so I'm confused as to why they won't work just on her laptop.

Any insight into this would be fantastic :)

Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem the same when you double-click the file to open it AND when you open it from within PowerPoint 2010 itself?

What happens if you create a very simple presentation (1 slide, nothing fancy) on your machine as a .pptx (2007, not 2003) and open it on her laptop?

Comment: This problem may still exist. On my system, PowerPoint 2010 won't open any files that have been *downloaded* until I follow the steps of user73901's workaround described below. Did you try creating a file on your friend's laptop and then opening it? I think that would probably work.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if I right-click on the troubled files, and select Properties, I find a Security message at the bottom of the General tab. There is a button to the right to "Unblock" the content from the file.  Once I clicked on that, the file opened just fine.

Comment: This is a workaround, but not an answer to truly fix the problem. Please see my comment on the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some my users using 2003  were having the same issue, after we pushed security update KB2464588.

We removed it and they were fine.

Remove any security update for powerpoint.

Microsoft blogged about this:[Here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/bgp/archive/2011/04/14/new-security-update-ms11-022.aspx)